# AWK — how to improve this example

Tags: awk

I have a file:

```
2012-11-15 10:35:00 2012 11 15 10 22 00
2012-11-14 13:03:00 2012 11 14 13 03 00
2012-11-14 13:13:00 2012 11 14 13 13 00
2012-11-14 13:23:00 2012 11 14 13 23 00
```

This command prints:

```
$ awk -F "\t" '{ system(" date -d \" "$1" \" +%s; date -d \" "$1" \" +%s ")}' file
1352972100
1352972100
1352894580
1352894580
1352895180
1352895180
1352895780
1352895780
```

I want to print in the system():

```
1352972100 1352972100
1352894580 1352894580
1352895180 1352895180 
1352895780 1352895780
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: +1 for sample input, expected output AND some code. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GNU awk. It's not clear which fields you're really getting the timestamp for printing from so here's some examples using your input file:

Using just $1:

```
$ gawk '{s=mktime(gensub(/-/," ","g",$1" 0 0 0")); print s,s}' file
1352959200 1352959200
1352872800 1352872800
1352872800 1352872800
1352872800 1352872800
```

Using $1 and $2:

```
$ gawk '{s=mktime(gensub(/[-:]/," ","g",$1" "$2)); print s,s}' file
1352997300 1352997300
1352919780 1352919780
1352920380 1352920380
1352920980 1352920980
```

Using $3 and on:

```
$ gawk '{sub($1" "$2" ","");s=mktime($0); print s,s}' file
1352996520 1352996520
1352919780 1352919780
1352920380 1352920380
1352920980 1352920980
```

If you don't have gawk:

```
$ awk '{ ("date -d \" "$1" \" +%s") | getline s; print s,s}' file
1352959200 1352959200
1352872800 1352872800
1352872800 1352872800
1352872800 1352872800
```

EDIT: Updated to how to use system() for this (NOT RECOMMENDED):

Take this shell command line:

```
$ printf "%s %s\n" $(date -d 2012/11/15 +%s) $(date -d 2012/11/15 +%s)
1352959200 1352959200
```

and invoke it from system() in awk:

```
$ awk '{system( "printf \"%s %s\n\" $(date -d " $1 " +%s) $(date -d " $1 " +%s)" )}' file
1352959200 1352959200
1352872800 1352872800
1352872800 1352872800
1352872800 1352872800
```

Comment: A good solution. Is it possible to do the same using system()?

Comment: Yes, but you'd need to write shell code to do it, not awk. That's not a great approach anyway though. I'll update my answer with an alternative that uses UNIX date but let us know if there's any particular reason you want to use system().

Comment: I have a very good reason to do so in the system(). I want to satisfy my curiosity. I know you can do this by getline, but I do not know how to do the system(). Thanks for another example.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. --> `awk  -F "\t" '{system( "printf \"%s %s\n\" $(date -d \" " $1 " \" +%s) $(date -d \" " $1 "\" +%s)" )}' file`

Comment: You're welcome. There's no mystery about system() - anything you want to go using system() you need to do with the shell script you're calling from system(), so write the shell script to do what you want, then put it into the system() call after escaping the quotes (and possibly backslashes). It's uses are pretty limited, in fact I can't think of one right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F "\t" '{ system(" echo $(date -d \" "$1" \" +%s; date -d \" "$1" \" +%s) ")}' file
```

This uses the `echo` command to flatten the two outputs into a single line.  It isn't a good solution, but it does meet the criterion of using system and producing the answer.  You could use this variant, too:

```
awk -F "\t" '{ system(" x=$(date -d \" "$1" \" +%s); echo $x $x ")}' file
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know that this is not a good solution, but I asked just out of curiosity.